# How to create a user of MongoDB created in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I´ve created a MongoDB instance using the Google Click to Deploy VM and I've added a firewall rule 0.0.0.0/0 and works fine using dataGrip or connecting from outside. But now I want to create an user account for obvious reasons and I don't know how to do it.
I've done it locally installing MongoDB and executing the command db.createUser(... but I don't know how to connect to the mongo db in google cloud and execute the same command in order to create the account.

Thanks and sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the click to deploy like you're describing, but my guess is, if you go here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

The instance that was created for you shows up, and in the row for the instance, look for the column that says `Connect`, you'll see a button that says `SSH`. Clicking that will open a window that will connect you to the VM. It should have the MongoDB client installed and you can run commands there as if you had installed it locally and create your user.